# is there any way that I can add my own custom c/c++ header file to where the standard header functions come from so that I can use them at any time

Tags: c++, c, header-files

I have written the implementations of some methods from my numerical analysis class in a header file. I did so because I need them frequently.
So I am wondering if there is any way in **c** or **c++** that I can add my own header files to somewhere, so that I can use it in my programs just like other **c/c++** standard header files/libraries whenever I need it.

Comment: yes, you can (simply put your header in the directory that contains things  such as <string>), but don't

Comment: It's generally a bad practice to put files in with your system headers. There are better places to add your own headers and these may depend on what compiler or IDE you are using and other factors like if you are using CMake or some other build system generator.